# Convert 3 columns from dataframe to date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have dataframe like this:

[image]

I want to convert the 'start_year', 'start_month', 'start_day' columns to date
and the columns 'end_year', 'end_month', 'end_day' to another date
There is a way to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach

- simulate some data as your data was an image
- use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) against each row to row series using `datetime.datetime()`

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "start_year": np.random.choice(range(2018, 2022), 10),
        "start_month": np.random.choice(range(1, 13), 10),
        "start_day": np.random.choice(range(1, 28), 10),
        "end_year": np.random.choice(range(2018, 2022), 10),
        "end_month": np.random.choice(range(1, 13), 10),
        "end_day": np.random.choice(range(1, 28), 10),
    }
)

df = df.apply(
    lambda r: r.append(pd.Series({f"{startend}_date": dt.datetime(*(r[f"{startend}_{part}"] 
                                                                    for part in ["year", "month", "day"]))
                                  for startend in ["start", "end"]})),
    axis=1)

df
```

|  | start_year | start_month | start_day | end_year | end_month | end_day | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2018 | 9 | 6 | 2020 | 1 | 3 | 2018-09-06 00:00:00 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2018 | 11 | 6 | 2020 | 7 | 2 | 2018-11-06 00:00:00 | 2020-07-02 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2021 | 8 | 13 | 2020 | 11 | 2 | 2021-08-13 00:00:00 | 2020-11-02 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 2021 | 3 | 15 | 2021 | 3 | 6 | 2021-03-15 00:00:00 | 2021-03-06 00:00:00 |
| 4 | 2019 | 4 | 13 | 2021 | 11 | 5 | 2019-04-13 00:00:00 | 2021-11-05 00:00:00 |
| 5 | 2021 | 2 | 5 | 2018 | 8 | 17 | 2021-02-05 00:00:00 | 2018-08-17 00:00:00 |
| 6 | 2020 | 4 | 19 | 2020 | 9 | 18 | 2020-04-19 00:00:00 | 2020-09-18 00:00:00 |
| 7 | 2020 | 3 | 27 | 2020 | 10 | 20 | 2020-03-27 00:00:00 | 2020-10-20 00:00:00 |
| 8 | 2019 | 12 | 23 | 2018 | 5 | 11 | 2019-12-23 00:00:00 | 2018-05-11 00:00:00 |
| 9 | 2021 | 7 | 18 | 2018 | 5 | 10 | 2021-07-18 00:00:00 | 2018-05-10 00:00:00 |

Answer (score 2):

Given a dataframe like this:

```py
     year  month   day
0  2019.0   12.0  29.0
1  2020.0    9.0  15.0
2  2018.0    3.0   1.0
```

You can convert them to date string using type cast, and `str.zfill`:

**OUTPUT:**

```py
df.apply(lambda x: f'{int(x["year"])}-{str(int(x["month"])).zfill(2)}-{str(int(x["day"])).zfill(2)}', axis=1)
0    2019-12-29
1    2020-09-15
2    2018-03-01
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

An interesting feature of pandasonic *to_datetime* function is that instead of
a sequence of **strings** you can pass to it a **whole DataFrame**.

But in this case there is a requirement that such a DataFrame must have columns
named *year*, *month* and *day*. They can be also of *float* type, like your source
DataFrame sample.

So a quite elegant solution is to:

- take a part of the source DataFrame (3 columns with the respective year,
  month and day),
- rename its columns to *year*, *month* and *day*,
- use it as the argument to *to_datetime*,
- save the result as a new column.

To do it, start from defining a *lambda* function, to be used as the rename
function below:

```
colNames = lambda x: x.split('_')[1]
```

Then just call:

```
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, 'start_year' : 'start_day']
    .rename(columns=colNames))
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, 'end_year' : 'end_day']
    .rename(columns=colNames))
```

For a sample of your source DataFrame, the result is:

```
   start_year  start_month  start_day   evidence_method_dating  end_year  end_month  end_day      Start        End
0      2019.0         12.0        9.0  Historical Observations    2019.0       12.0      9.0 2019-12-09 2019-12-09
1      2019.0          2.0       18.0  Historical Observations    2019.0        7.0     28.0 2019-02-18 2019-07-28
2      2018.0          7.0        3.0               Seismicity    2019.0        8.0     20.0 2018-07-03 2019-08-20
```

Maybe the next part should be to remove columns with parts of both "start"
and "end" dates. Your choice.

## Edit

To avoid saving the *lambda* (anonymous) function under a variable, define
this function as a regular (named) function:

```
def colNames(x):
    return x.split('_')[1]
```

Comment: don't assign anonymous function to a variable!

Comment: Generally yes. But in this time it is advisable to have this (lambda) function saved in a variable. This way you can pass it twice, instead of passing the same lambda function multiple times.